# IEs understanding of 'this'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

In this code, Firefox sees 'this' as the element that was clicked and passes the href attribute through the right way.

IE seems to think that 'this' as [object window] instead. How would I get this to work the same way in both browsers?

Note: jQuery would be lovely, but is not an option for this project

```
var printElem = getElementsByClassName('print', 'a');
for(i in printElem){
    ObserveEvent(printElem[i], 'click', function(e){
        window.open(this.href, '', 'location=0,menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width='+810+',height='+700);
        cancelEvent(e);
    });
}
```

Comment: This code lives in an event handler?

Comment: What is your `ObserveEvent` function?

Comment: If so, it must be < 1.6. In Prototype, from 1.6 onward, Prototype ensures that the element you watched is what `this` references (which may be different from the one the event was trigger by, because most events bubble -- very handy distinction).

Comment: Hmmm... not sure what version it was extracted from, there is a possibility that it was broken when it happened though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm adding my two cents here as I think you can use it.

There was a [contest 4 years ago](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/addevent_recodi.html) to see who could write the best `addEvent` implementation. One of the main problems it tried to address was retaining `this` inside the event handler.

Here is [one contest entry](http://ejohn.org/blog/flexible-javascript-events/) written by the creator of jQuery:

```
function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
  if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
    obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
    obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
    obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
  } else
    obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
}
```

(And of course to be symmetrical):

```
function removeEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
  if ( obj.detachEvent ) {
    obj.detachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
    obj[type+fn] = null;
  } else
    obj.removeEventListener( type, fn, false );
}
```

Rename it to "ObserveEvent" if you wish.

There you have it, an 8 line implementation you can drop into your codebase - No libraries, no frameworks. And your `this` reference inside your handler works just fine.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I still would love to transition to a framework to add a bit more consistency to the code.

Comment: +1 from me :) doesn't prototype depend on the method, though? i.e. is the patching safe?

Comment: @Alexander: very gracious of you :) I think I know what you mean. I don't condone patching the prototype library, no. However as I read the question I think they just ripped the code from the innards of prototype, in which case they can patch their own code to their heart's content.

Comment: Yes @crescentfresh, you are right, it was ripped unceremoniously from it before I joined the company

Comment: No need to rely on function decompilation for something as simple as `addEvent`.

Comment: @kangax: I know. Aesthetically speaking I actually hate this implementation myself. Resig can get way too clever sometimes, with a high WTF factor. Anyway, as an answer it was meant to specifically address SeanJA's issue with `this`, and to mention there was a whole contest around this very problem.

Comment: @kangax: Oh and also to show how something as simple as `addEvent` can be.

Comment: @crescentfresh It's good to hear you agree :) This is of course not just an aesthetic issue. There are real implications from this "clever" approach (I wrote about why decompilation sucks some time ago - http://thinkweb2.com/projects/prototype/detecting-built-in-host-methods/, http://thinkweb2.com/projects/prototype/those-tricky-functions/). Ironically, we still use decompilation in Prototype.js (for compatibility reasons), but are removing it in future (back-incompatible) releases.

Comment: @kangax: nice writeups in both articles. Good work. Relying on "function decompilation" is indeed non-standard, akin to `navigator` sniffing and prone to suckage. (I never realized all the browser differences wrt to `Function.prototype.toString()` btw, thanks). I do just want to point out however that Resig is nowhere relying on any browser-specific string representation of the function. He uses the string representation, sure, but does not test against it (in any "conditional" sense).

Comment: @crescentfresh No, of course, he doesn't. The problem here is that by specification, 1 single function object can return 2 different representations. In a similar manner, 2 different function objects can return 1 identical representation. This on its own already breaks the premise of `addEvent` being able to filter out identical submissions (which is what `addEventListener` does, for example). It also means that attaching 2 different event handlers can result in second one overwriting first one (if their representation is identical). You get the point :)

Comment: @kangax: if I had say two `Class` instances `a` and `b`, each with a `doClick` method (i.e. on the class `prototype`), and I go: `addEvent(el, 'click', a.doClick); addEvent(el, 'click', b.doClick);`, it fails. `addEventListener` gets it right and knows they are different functions (adds each as it should). Resig's `addEvent` sees them as the same and overwrites, effectively discarding the first `addEvent()`. I see know, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [event target](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target), like this:

```
    ObserveEvent(printElem[i], 'click', function(e){
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            window.open(target.href, '', 'location=0,menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width='+810+',height='+700);
            cancelEvent(e);
    });
```

Comment: Damn... I was most of the way there, I had e.target I was missing the e.srcElement part. Thanks

Comment: This will fail if `printElem[i]` contains children and one of *those* is clicked.

Comment: Well, in the future, you could write a `contains` function to determine whether the target element is within the printElem[i]. But if it doesn't have any children, keep it simple ;)

Comment: @Alexander: how does a `contains` implementation help? You need to traverse *up* to the clicked anchor. All this is solved by an `ObserveEvent` implementation that **retains references to `this`**, like the question asked for in the first place.

Comment: @crescentfresh: If only I could convince the boss that a switch to jQuery/any other full javascript framework would be beneficial

Comment: Well, yes, they have a great event handler implementation - and indeed, retaining the `this` reference is important - I am just proposing a solution to the problem, rather than answering the question directly.

Comment: @SeanJA: OK I'm adding my own answer to help out here. I think you can use it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem almost certainly stems from the `ObserveEvent` function using IE's `attachEvent` method, which (unlike `addEventListener` in other browsers) doesn't set `this` to the object being observed in the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Another option: Create a closure to scope the element for the handler for each element:

```
var printElem = getElementsByClassName('print', 'a');
for(var i in printElem){
  (function(elem) { // elem === printElem[i] at time of execution later
    ObserveEvent(elem, 'click', function(e){
      window.open(elem.href, '', 'location=0,menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width='+810+',height='+700);
      cancelEvent(e);
    });
  })(printElem[i]); // immediately call the temp function with our element
}
```