# Event Handling in IE

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have the code included below that allows me to do something the first time a user mouses over an element and then remove the event.

It plays nice in the W3C event model browsers but keeps throwing an error in IE6-8. I got the code from another question and believed it would handle IE. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setMouseEvent() {
        //Tel: 01 8279 400
        event = addEvent(document.getElementById('contactButton'), 'mouseover', changeText);
    }

    function changeText() {
        alert("worked!");
        removeEvent(document.getElementById('contactButton'), 'mouseover', changeText);
    }

    function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
        if (typeof obj.addEventListener != undefined) {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        }
        else if (typeof obj.attachEvent != undefined) {
            obj.attachEvent("on" + type, fn);
        }
    }

    function removeEvent(obj, type, fn) {
        if (typeof obj.addEventListener != undefined) {
            obj.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
        }
        else if (typeof obj.attachEvent != undefined) {
            obj.detachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
            obj[type + fn] = null;
            obj["e" + type + fn] = null;
        }
    }
    
    window.onload = setMouseEvent;
</script>
```

**Update:** I just tested in the latest Chrome, Opera and Firefox with no issues but Safari does nothing when I mouse over and IE is throwing the errors `onload` as mentioned.

Comment: Yuck. Where'd you get `removeEvent`? Looks similar to John Resig's implementation (http://ejohn.org/blog/flexible-javascript-events/), but not symmetrical with `addEvent`.

Comment: Maybe I'm just a simpleton, but if this were my page I'd deal with the one-shot event handler with a simple flag variable that I'd flip after the first invocation. If I *really* wanted to do a lot of event wrangling, I'd let some well-tested framework deal with the ugly details.

Comment: I was close to just grabbing jQuery again but wanted to dig a little this time. Always wanna keep learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
event = addEvent(
```

`addEvent` doesn't return anything; you're assigning the `undefined` lack-of-return-value to a global variable `event` (since you've not said `var event` in the function). This will cause an exception in IE, which uses the global `event` as a special object to pass event details to handlers, and consequently doesn't allow you to assign something else to it.

```
if (typeof obj.addEventListener != undefined)
```

`typeof` always returns a string, which will never test equal to the `undefined` unvalue, so IE will always take the non-IE fork and fail. You meant `if (typeof obj.addEventListener !== 'undefined')`, with a string.

```
obj.detachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
```

Since you've not written a property with the name of `type` and `fn` stuck together in the `addEvent` function, this will fail to retrieve anything.

As Crescent says, it looks like you're using Resig's `removeEvent` function, paired with a different `addEvent` that doesn't match. If you use his `removeEvent` you will need to use his `addEvent` to go with it.

However, I wouldn't use these functions anyway: they're pretty dodgy. I know it was 2005 when this ill-conceived code ‘won’ quirksmode's addEvent contest, but even then we should have known a lot better. The problem is it creates a string from the event name and the textual serialisation of the function code (`type+fn`), and uses it as a key to store a callback. This key will look something like `'mouseoverfunction changeText() {...code...}'`.

But relying on function serialisation is a terrible idea. The format is not standardised by ECMAScript (“An implementation-dependent representation of the function is returned.”); there are [many browser quirks](http://perfectionkills.com/those-tricky-functions/); and not least, two different functions can easily return the same string for browsers' current serialisation methods:

```
var f1= function() {};
var f2= function() {};
```

`f1` and `f2` will have the same string serialisation, but they're not the same object. If you did an `addEvent` for `f1` on IE, and then another one for `f2`, the second property would use the same serialised string and overwrite the first property. Then calling `removeEvent` for `f1` would retrieve the function for `f2`, try to `detachEvent` it and fail because it's not the same function. This example may look contrived, but it's actually extremely easy to do accidentally when you're using generic closures, as modern JavaScript does more and more these days. For this reason I'd recommend **avoiding Resig's `addEvent` in all circumstances**.

(jQuery users: don't worry, for all its problems jQuery does not fall into the trap of using this code.)

This hack is there to preserve the `this` value when your `changeText` function is called back by IE, whose `attachEvent` doesn't set `this`. But you don't even use the `this` value, so you could have got away with a much simpler version, such as the [original addEvent](http://www.scottandrew.com/weblog/articles/cbs-events) it was created to replace.

At least the shortcomings of *that* addEvent are well-known and show up immediately when you test on IE using `this`, instead of only going wrong in a particular case that, when it affects you, is likely to be extremely confusing and hard to debug.

Then again, you aren't currently using even multiple listeners for the same event, so you could easily get away with a old-fashioned DOM Level 0 event handler, something like:

```
window.onload= function() {
    var changed= false;
    document.getElementById('contactButton').onmouseover= function() {
        if (!changed) {
            alert('changing text');
        }
        changed= true;
    };
};
```

Comment: I think this is the first answer on SO that addresses the suckage of Resig's `addEvent` entry. There was a brief exchange in the comments of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466875/ies-understanding-of-this/1471006#1471006 where kangax enlightened me on the failures of relying on function decompilation/serialization for identifying a function object. Good write up. A++++++++

Answer (score 1):

Go for **[Dean's addEvent](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/)**, if you want a flexible solution:

```
// written by Dean Edwards, 2005
// with input from Tino Zijdel, Matthias Miller, Diego Perini
// http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/

function addEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        // assign each event handler a unique ID
        if (!handler.$$guid) handler.$$guid = addEvent.guid++;
        // create a hash table of event types for the element
        if (!element.events) element.events = {};
        // create a hash table of event handlers for each element/event pair
        var handlers = element.events[type];
        if (!handlers) {
            handlers = element.events[type] = {};
            // store the existing event handler (if there is one)
            if (element["on" + type]) {
                handlers[0] = element["on" + type];
            }
        }
        // store the event handler in the hash table
        handlers[handler.$$guid] = handler;
        // assign a global event handler to do all the work
        element["on" + type] = handleEvent;
    }
};
// a counter used to create unique IDs
addEvent.guid = 1;

function removeEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.removeEventListener) {
        element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        // delete the event handler from the hash table
        if (element.events && element.events[type]) {
            delete element.events[type][handler.$$guid];
        }
    }
};

function handleEvent(event) {
    var returnValue = true;
    // grab the event object (IE uses a global event object)
    event = event || fixEvent(((this.ownerDocument || this.document || this).parentWindow || window).event);
    // get a reference to the hash table of event handlers
    var handlers = this.events[event.type];
    // execute each event handler
    for (var i in handlers) {
        this.$$handleEvent = handlers[i];
        if (this.$$handleEvent(event) === false) {
            returnValue = false;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
};

function fixEvent(event) {
    // add W3C standard event methods
    event.preventDefault = fixEvent.preventDefault;
    event.stopPropagation = fixEvent.stopPropagation;
    return event;
};
fixEvent.preventDefault = function() {
    this.returnValue = false;
};
fixEvent.stopPropagation = function() {
    this.cancelBubble = true;
};
```