# Best way to add an event to an element without a library or using the onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, click, dom-events

So I want an element i.e: `<a id="target">click me</a>` to perform a JavaScript function i.e:
`functionName();`
I want to avoid using the "on" attributes i.e: `onclick=""`.
By cross-browser I mean the [A-grade browser compatibility list from YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/#gbschart)

Comment: just curious why you don't want to use onclick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById("target");
var old = el.onclick;
el.onclick = function() {
  if(old) old();
  functionName();
  // if you want to prevent default action
  // return false; 
};​
```

For a more robust solution, see: **[Dean Edward's addEvent](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/)**.

Comment: Nice, so what's the main danger of using this opposed to DE's addEvent?

Comment: there is no danger, it's just not including event bubbling, or the ability to remove events. So for simple things this will do, but if you want to do some advanced event handling, Dean's script offers a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks, nice concise answer with explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('target').onclick=function() {
  functionName();
  return false;
}
```

I assume you meant "without onclick html attribute"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getElementById` method to find the element, and set it's onclick event:

```
document.getElementById('target').onclick = functionName;
```

Comment: it rewrites the current onclick handler, not adds a new one to it

Comment: @galambalazs: Yes, that is actually what the OP asked for, not more, not less.

Comment: @Guffa and if he asks for a knife to commit suicide? You hand it to him eagerly? I may consider convincing him not to do things that he may regret. :)

Comment: but see, the ultimate answer is John Resig's addEvent from 2005 which was abandoned even by Resig. :)

Comment: @galambalazs: So you are saying that the code is dangerous to use? Do you have any references for that?

Comment: @galambalazs: And that is dangerous how?

Comment: @Guffa you overwrite an onclick handler that was attached for a reason, and you break some functionality as a result.

Comment: @galambalazs: That might be exactly the behaviour that is intended. Keeping the previous event handler might be just as dangerous.

Comment: @Guffa And **might** is the world that is emphasized here. The concept of event handlers involves adding and removing handlers on a target. So a script that attached the handler should be able to call it or remove if not needed. And no script should possess absolute power over an event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this counts as a library, but here are the addEvent() and removeEvent() functions written by John Resig (yes, [that John Resig](http://jquery.com/)):

```
function addEvent( obj, type, fn )
{
    if (obj.addEventListener)
    {
        obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent)
    {
        obj["e"+type+fn] = fn;
        obj[type+fn] = function() { obj["e"+type+fn]( window.event ); };
        obj.attachEvent( "on"+type, obj[type+fn] );
    }
}

function removeEvent( obj, type, fn )
{
    if (obj.removeEventListener)
    {
        obj.removeEventListener( type, fn, false );
    }
    else if (obj.detachEvent)
    {
        obj.detachEvent( "on"+type, obj[type+fn] );
        obj[type+fn] = null;
        obj["e"+type+fn] = null;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('target'), 'click', functionName);
removeEvent(document.getElementById('target'), 'click', functionName);
```

Comment: :) omg, that John Resig? I jeez in my pants.... Please note that even Resig is using Dean Edward's event handler in jQuery. Let's read the related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185513/event-handling-in-ie/